# How to set up a different context to point to an external directory outside webapps Tomcat/Java

Tags: java, tomcat

I am successful to map an external directory by creating an xml file like :

**`<Context path="/uploads" docBase="C:\uploads\photos" crossContext="true"/>`**

And I named this xml file as uploads.xml and saved under "#Tomcat\conf\Catalina\localhost" here # = Directory where Tomcat has been installed.
And when I start Tomcat(5) from cammand line (batch file) i.e. startup.bat
The images can be accessed normally like
"http://localhost:8080/uploads/user1.png"

It works.

Actually I am using IntelliJ Idea 8 for devevelopment.
When I start Tomcat from IntelliJ Idea, I am not able to access the context i.e. the images.
"http://localhost:8080/uploads/user1.png"
It shows "HTTP 400 Bad Request"

The context path for my project is 
"http://localhost:8080/spark/"

Any help or suggestion is needed at the earliest time.

Looking forward to as many appreciative responses as possible.

Thanx
Pink

Comment: <Context 
 path="/uploads" 
 docBase="C:\uploads\photos"
 crossContext="true"
   />

Comment: so, you answered your question?

Comment: IntelliJ 8?  They've just released version 10.

Comment: I don't do IntelliJ, but if it were Eclipse, you should configure the server plugin to take the entire server over instead of only deploying the workspace data to server. This way any existing external webapps/contexts (which are not controlled by the IDE) will be deployed as well when you start the server. Look if similar option exist in IntelliJ's server config.

Comment: hey BallusC, Tomcat has a server.xml file and even I tried putting the same docBase context in that, still it does not reflect as I wanted. The issue I am encountering is that IntelliJ Idea starts up Tomcat from its Tomcat Context Descriptor. I cant find a good way out yet.

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ uses it's own Tomcat Base, so you will need to add a web facet to your project and add your directory there.  This is for IntellijJ 9 and 10.  I don't have 8.

Comment: thanx Zeki Yeah we have a context.xml where we define the current context i.e. spark for example "http://localhost:8080/spark"
this is located at ../WebRoot/META-INF/context.xml.
This is set up in Tomcat Context Descriptor in Facets of IntelliJ Idea. Can we somehow define another xml file which maps to an external directory outside the webapps. If so, how can define another context specifically for images (uploads and fetching into the presentation layer) Please let me know.